# Show that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln n} \left(1+\tan\frac{1}{n} \right)^{2019}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Show that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln n} \left(1+\tan\frac{1}{n} \right)^{2019}$$ converges.

I wanted to use the alternating series test with $b_{n} = \frac{(1+\tan\frac{1}{n})^{2019}}{\ln n}$ but so far this hasn't worked out for me, so I feel like this is the wrong test. Do you know which test would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternating series test is the correct one.  Which part of it isn't working for you?

Comment: The $tan\frac{1}{n}$ is really bothering me. I don't know how to show it's decreasing and a positive sequence. That's about it.

Comment: $\tan$ is an increasing positive function on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$, and $1/n$ is in that interval and decreasing...

Comment: I see, so the series only decreases in that interval?

Comment: No, the terms of the series are decreasing because $1/n$ is in that interval...

Comment: $0 < \dfrac{1}{n+1} < \dfrac{1}{n} < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ so $0 < \tan\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) < \tan\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$.